# Donde validamos presentacion o negocio?

Tags: c#

estoy haciendo una aplicación c# (desktop | Windows Forms)y para validar los campos ejemplo un textBox lo hago desde la capa de presentación, Ahora bien, tengo otra validación que dice "el empleado no puede tener 2 cuentas de usuario" así que busco en el datagridview si ese id de empleado existe entonces no puede crear otro usuario.

**Pregunta 1:** Este tipo de validación va en la capa de lógica de negocio o en presentación?

**Pregunta 2:(multiple)** y ultima pregunta, en caso de que todas estas validaciones se hagan en presentación, que pasa si decido hacer una nueva vista? todos mis métodos tendría que escribirlos nuevamente? No es preferible que todas las validaciones de formularios sean parte de lógica de negocio?

Ejemplo de validación que hago en capa presentación.
En este ejemplo verifico si el empleado ya tiene usuario asignado, buscando un empleado idéntico en el datagridview.

```
        private bool TieneUsuario(string EmpleadoRepetido)
    {
        bool existe = false;
        List<NombreEmpleado> listaEmpleado = new List<NombreEmpleado>();
        foreach (var item in dgv_Usuarios.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>())
        {
            listaEmpleado.Add(new NombreEmpleado {
                nombreEmpleado = item.Cells["id_empleado"].Value.ToString()
            });
        }
        foreach (var item in listaEmpleado)
        {
            if (item.nombreEmpleado.ToString() == EmpleadoRepetido)
            {
                existe = true;
            }
        }
        return existe;
```

Desde ya mucha gracias.

Comment: Podrías comentar qué tecnología estás usando? Dices que es c# (desktop). Pero es Windows Forms, WPF, UWP?

Comment: Estimado ahí mismo edito la pregunta y agrego, uso Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola a la pregunta numero uno: en la capa de negocios. deberías hacer un método que controle en la base de datos si ya tiene cuenta o no. Justamente que no pueda tener dos cuentas es una regla de negocio (tal vez después esa restricción se modifique)
Con respecto a la pregunta numero dos: depende que estas controlando, espacios en blanco cantidad de caracteres deberías controlarlos en la vista.
Espero que te ayude mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta, si, justamente me hiciste notar que estoy verificando la existencia de usuario en un datagridview y no en la base de datos como debiera hacer. Muchas gracias, tu respuesta junto con la de Leandro me aclaro el panorama.

Answer (score 0):

La teoria indica que las validaciones deberias ralizarlas en presentacion y negocio, pero en la practica muy pocas veces lo realzias de esta forma.

Hay validaciones que claramente son de presentacion y otras que solo pueden realizarse en negocio.

Por ejemplo si vas a validar que un TextBox solo permita ingresar numeros, o definir un numero determinado de caracteres estos es claramente de presentacion, pero podrias validarlo en negocio tambine si usas librerias como ser

[fluentvalidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/)

con este tipo de librerias puedes definir reglas que aplican a las propiedades del medelo de negocio, entonces las ejecutas tanto en la UI como en el negocio para tener la validacion en ambos lados

Despues hay validaciones que solo pueden realizarse en la capa de negocio, como por ejemplo si existe un nro de cuenta, o como en el ejemplo que mencionaste sino puede tener mas de dos asignadas, esto no se valida en la prsentacion, porque deberias ir a la db filtrando por el empleado y ver si aplica esa regla qeue solo el negocio puede determinar.

Si podrias poder una restriccion light en la presentacion en el nro de registros de cuentas que se pueden seleccionar, pero es algo simple, la validacion firme la realizas en el negocio.

Esto que menciono aplica muy fuerte si conecta la `UI` con una `Web API` en donde ambas capas se separan fisicamente de forma muy notable. Ademas al exponer una web api por lo general se plantea que terceras aplicaciones pueden consumir los servicios, con lo cual debe ser mas ribusta la validacion.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta, como mi validación de "empleado ya tiene cuenta" no consulta a la base sino al datagridview pensé que iba en presentación, igual ya me doy cuenta que no consulto en tiempo real mas bien consulto una copia de una tabla en una ventana, con urgencia debo modificar esto y hacer la consulta en la propia base.
Muchas gracias me dejaste todo bastante claro.